# Calling type function for a member of map

Tags: go

I'm coding a communication protocol. It sends tokens, which I need to use to authenticate.
I have created a type, "AuthToken" that encodes/decodes the token for me.

In the package "utils", I declare it and some of the functions like this (this is like a pseudo-code):

```
package utils

type AuthToken struct{
   // vars
}

func (token *AuthToken) Decode(encoded string){
   // Decodes the token and fills internal fields
}

func (token AuthToken) GetField() string{
   return field
}
```

In  my main package, I want to create a map of AuthTokens to store them, but I can't use the function Decode in a member of the map, while I can use GetField:

```
package main

type TokenList map[string]utils.AuthToken

func main(){
   tokenList := make(TokenList)
   // To init one member I do:
   tokenList["1"] = utils.AuthToken{} // This works
   tokenList["2"] = make(utils.AuthToken) // This doesn't
   // Then I need to call the function above, so I tried:
   tokenList["1"].Decode("encoded") // Returns cannot call pointer method
```

I have tried searching for it, but either I don't know where to search, or there is no info about how to do this.

Comment: `make` is for maps, slices, and channels. Not for structs. `utils.AuthToken` is a struct.

Comment: As an alternative to the answer below, you could change the tokenlist to `type TokenList map[string]*utils.AuthToken`. And then use `tokenList["1"] = &utils.AuthToken{}` or `tokenList["2"] = new(utils.AuthToken)` (note `new` can be used with structs), then `tokenList["1"].Decode("encoded")` will work.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
tokenList["2"] = make(utils.AuthToken) // This doesn't
```

You cannot use `make` keyword to instantiate an object from struct. That's the reason why above statement wont work.

---

```golang
tokenList["1"] = utils.AuthToken{}
tokenList["1"].Decode("encoded") // Returns cannot call pointer method
```

The `tokenList["1"]` returns non pointer object. You will need to store it into a variable, then from there do access the pointer, only then you will be able to call `.Decode()` method.

```golang
obj := tokenList["1"]
objPointer := &obj
objPointer.Decode("encoded")
```

Comment: Two questions for it. I guess there is no way to do it directly, I need a pointer right? By doing that, when I call .Decode(), it also changes the obkect in tokenList["1"], right? So structs in golang works like a pointer itself?

Comment: @josesnchz You need a pointer or an addressable value. A map index expression does not evaluate to an addressable value. A plain variable is addressable though so you **do not** need `objPointer := &obj`, you can just do `obj.Decode("encoded")` (because `obj` **is** addressable). Or use a pointer type as the map's element type, just like I've shown in my comment to your question, then `m[k].M()` will work just fine.

Comment: @josesnchz note one thing, if you use non-pointer type as the map's element type, and then you do `obj := tokenList["1"]`; `obj.Decode("encoded")` this will not update the value in the `tokenList` map, you'll have to add a 3rd statement that stores the modified `obj` in the map, i.e. `tokenList["1"] = obj`.

Comment: I just came here to ask about it, I tried doing it without that statement and that did not work. I will go with the pointer option, which I think is more clear